# Managing Site Feature ends up in Error

Tags: 2013, site-collection, publishing

I am trying to turn on the Page-Layout-Option for my SharePoint Site-Collection.

I have turned on the SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure (see below)

[image]

Then I am trying to activate this Feature "SharePoint Server Publishing" (see below)

[image]

But this ends up in following screen:

[image]

So I am getting a server error, but when I am going back to the Home screen everything works normal.

I am running SP as Site Collection-Administrator.

Is there anything I am missing?

EDIT:

I have enable the SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure on Site-Collection level and trying to activate the SharePoint Server Publishing Feature on Site level.

The shown error is occuring while the activation of the SharePoint Server Publishing Feature.

Comment: status code 503 means app pool is not running. I would deactivate the feature and re activate it. did you enable on subsite or site collection level? at what level you getting the error?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE have adapted my question